# ambiguous of the custom_buttonfield

Tags: layout, blackberry, custom-fields

[This](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/320iconnews.png/) is the original button image. The background of the button was transparent.

When apply into apps, the button look like [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/72/21387545.png/). Please look at top left the button. The background of the button became gray instead of transparent.

[Here](http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/1194/sc20120719145312.png) is the Android version's button.

Not only the button but also all same type of buttons which background was transparent.

The `custom_buttonfield`

```
public class Custom_ButtonField extends ButtonField {
Bitmap mNormal;
Bitmap mFocused;
Bitmap mActive;

int mWidth;
int mHeight;

private int color = -1;
String text;

public Custom_ButtonField(Bitmap normal, Bitmap focused, Bitmap active) {
    super(CONSUME_CLICK | Field.FOCUSABLE | Field.FIELD_HCENTER
            | Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
    mNormal = normal;
    mFocused = focused;
    mActive = active;
    mWidth = mNormal.getWidth();
    mHeight = mNormal.getHeight();
    setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE,
            BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
}

public Custom_ButtonField(String text, Bitmap normal, Bitmap focused,
        Bitmap active, int color) {
    super(CONSUME_CLICK | Field.FOCUSABLE | Field.FIELD_HCENTER
            | Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
    this.color = color;
    mNormal = normal;
    mFocused = focused;
    mActive = active;
    mWidth = mNormal.getWidth();
    mHeight = mNormal.getHeight();
    setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE,
            BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    this.text = text;
}

protected void onFocus(int direction) {
    super.onFocus(direction);
}

protected void onUnfocus() {
    super.onUnfocus();
}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {   
    int fontcontent;
    if (Display.getWidth() > 480)
        fontcontent = 28;
    else if (Display.getWidth() < 481 && Display.getWidth() > 320)
        fontcontent = 23;
    else
        fontcontent = 18;

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    switch (getVisualState()) {
    case VISUAL_STATE_NORMAL:
        bitmap = mNormal;
        break;
    case VISUAL_STATE_FOCUS:
        bitmap = mFocused;
        break;
    case VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE:
        bitmap = mActive;
        break;
    default:
        bitmap = mNormal;
    }
    graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
            bitmap, 0, 0);
    graphics.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, fontcontent));
    graphics.setColor(color);
    graphics.drawText(text, (mNormal.getWidth() - Font.getDefault()
            .getAdvance(text)) / 2, ((mNormal.getHeight() - Font
            .getDefault().getHeight()) / 2) + 10, DrawStyle.HCENTER
            | DrawStyle.VCENTER);
}

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return mWidth;
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return mHeight;
}

protected void layout(int width, int height) {
    setExtent(mWidth, mHeight);
}
}
```

The loader is here

```
private Bitmap news = Config_GlobalFunction.Bitmap("icon_news.png");
private Bitmap newsactive = Config_GlobalFunction
        .Bitmap("icon_news_active.png");

if (left == 1) {
        newsbtn = new Custom_ButtonField(news, newsactive, newsactive) {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                Main.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
                        new Menu_PopupMenu(thisid));
                return true;
            }
        };

        add(newsbtn);
    } else if (left == 2) {
        backbtn = new Custom_ButtonField(back, backctive, backctive) {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                Main.getUiApplication().popScreen(mainscreen);
                return true;
            }
        };
        add(backbtn);
    }

if (left == 1) {
        field = getField(1);
        layoutChild(field, back.getWidth(), back.getHeight());
        setPositionChild(field, 10, Height);
    } else if (left == 2) {
        field = getField(1);
        layoutChild(field, news.getWidth(), news.getHeight());
        setPositionChild(field, 10, Height);
    }
```

if I set like this `layoutChild(field, 60, 60);`, then it got no problem, the behind gray color no more. However, I cannot set fixed and must dynamic size.

Comment: add some code. show the button code ?

Comment: ... the button code, and the code used to load the `Bitmap`, or `PNGEncodedImage`, or whatever you're using, would help us solve this.

Comment: @Nate, this problem I also don't know why like that, the black bar's button also same. The android version I upload the image

Comment: Ok, but where is the code that loads the `news` and `newsactive` images?  How are those images created? Do, you just use `Bitmap.getBitmapResource()`?

Comment: all related code has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call this `setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bitmap));`
 instead of `graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
            bitmap, 0, 0);` in `Custom_ButtonField`.

Comment: You can Accept your own answer, so everyone knows that this problem has been solved.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the actual code that's loading the `Bitmap` objects, but I know you were discussing it in the other question you posted.  Try this:

Config_GlobalFunction.java:

```java
public static Bitmap Bitmap(String name) {
    Bitmap result;

    // do whatever you do to load the Bitmap (e.g. Bitmap.getBitmapResource(name))

    result.createAlpha(Bitmap.ALPHA_BITDEPTH_8BPP);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: it became more worst instead of transparent.

Comment: @AlanLai, can you post the actual image you are using, that's having problems?  Not a **screenshot** of the image.  Just take the exact image (.png file) that you use for this button, and put it on a website, and then post a link to it in the question.  Different images have different properties, so there could be different reasons why this isn't working.  But, I think I would need to have the actual PNG file that you're using.  Thanks!

Comment: the problem I found which was `drawbitmap`. This method will draw the bitmap. Then I use `setbackground()` it works what I want.