# How to detect whether field is touched or clicked?

Tags: blackberry, touch-event

I override the method like this.

```java
        newsbtn = new Custom_ButtonField(news, newsactive, newsactive) {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                Main.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
                        new Menu_PopupMenu(position));
                return true;
            }

            protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
                int eventCode = message.getEvent();
                if (eventCode == TouchEvent.UNCLICK){
                    Main.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
                            new Menu_PopupMenu(position));
                }
                return true;
            }
        };

        add(newsbtn);
```

Here is the `Custom_ButtonField`

```java
public class Custom_ButtonField extends ButtonField {
Bitmap mNormal;
Bitmap mFocused;
Bitmap mActive;

int mWidth;
int mHeight;

private int color = -1;
String text;

public Custom_ButtonField(Bitmap normal, Bitmap focused, Bitmap active) {
    super(CONSUME_CLICK | Field.FOCUSABLE | Field.FIELD_HCENTER
            | Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
    mNormal = normal;
    mFocused = focused;
    mActive = active;
    mWidth = mNormal.getWidth();
    mHeight = mNormal.getHeight();
    setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE,
            BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
}

public Custom_ButtonField(String text, Bitmap normal, Bitmap focused,
        Bitmap active, int color) {
    super(CONSUME_CLICK | Field.FOCUSABLE | Field.FIELD_HCENTER
            | Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
    this.color = color;
    mNormal = normal;
    mFocused = focused;
    mActive = active;
    mWidth = mNormal.getWidth();
    mHeight = mNormal.getHeight();
    setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE,
            BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    this.text = text;
}

public Custom_ButtonField(String text, Bitmap normal, Bitmap focused,
        Bitmap active, int color, long style) {
    super(style);
    this.color = color;
    mNormal = normal;
    mFocused = focused;
    mActive = active;
    mWidth = mNormal.getWidth();
    mHeight = mNormal.getHeight();
    setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE,
            BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    this.text = text;
}

public void setText(String text){
    this.text = text;
    invalidate();
}

public String getText(){
    return text;
}

public void setColor(int color){
    this.color = color;
}

protected void onFocus(int direction) {     
    super.onFocus(direction);
    color = 0x540604;
    this.invalidate();
}

protected void onUnfocus() {
    super.onUnfocus();
    color = Color.WHITE;
    this.invalidate();
}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    int fontcontent;
    if (Display.getWidth() > 480)
        fontcontent = 28;
    else if (Display.getWidth() < 481 && Display.getWidth() > 320)
        fontcontent = 23;
    else
        fontcontent = 18;

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    switch (getVisualState()) {
    case VISUAL_STATE_NORMAL:
        bitmap = mNormal;
        break;
    case VISUAL_STATE_FOCUS:
        bitmap = mFocused;
        break;
    case VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE:
        bitmap = mActive;
        break;
    default:
        bitmap = mNormal;
    }
    setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bitmap));
    graphics.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, fontcontent));
    graphics.setColor(color);
    graphics.drawText(text, (mNormal.getWidth() - Font.getDefault()
            .getAdvance(text)) / 2, ((mNormal.getHeight() - Font
            .getDefault().getHeight()) / 2) + 10, DrawStyle.HCENTER
            | DrawStyle.VCENTER);
}

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return mWidth;
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return mHeight;
}

protected void layout(int width, int height) {
    setExtent(mWidth, mHeight);
}
}
```

However, the button unable to perform push screen and only `setfocus()` on the button.

Comment: Can you post your full Custom_ButtonField class? I know there's another question of your that had it, but I'm not sure if you made changes since then.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use the `CONSUME_CLICK` constructor field, just to **get** clicks.  That determines whether or not the field **consumes** click events, or lets them propagate to other classes to handle.  But, the poster's code is already returning `true` in his two click handling methods, which also means *"I've already handled this click ... don't bother passing it to other `Field` classes"*.  [See more on this here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/ButtonField-CONSUME-CLICK-what-is-it-for/td-p/190434)

And as Alan said in his comment, he was already using `CONSUME_CLICK`, so that's definitely not the problem.

If the `Custom_ButtonField` class is the same one [you posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553286/ambiguous-of-the-custom-buttonfield), then I am able to get clicks just fine when I use your code.  However, there's one potential problem I could see.  You don't show your Java imports.  Does your `TouchEvent` import look like this?

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.TouchEvent;
```

There's actually another `TouchEvent` class in the BlackBerry frameworks, and if you used the wrong one, then you've created a method that doesn't actually override the base class `touchEvent()`.  It's easy to use the Eclipse shortcut to put in your imports, but it's possible to get the wrong one.

I think if you do this, though, Eclipse should show a warning that the incorrect version of `touchEvent()` is never called.

**Edit:** by the way, I usually trigger my click handling code on the `TouchEvent.UNCLICK` event, not on `TouchEvent.CLICK`. I think that makes for a better UI.  The click doesn't register until the user's finger has been lifted.  But, that's a minor thing, and isn't the reason for this problem.

Comment: When I click the button, It only changed the image and `focus` only but not perform `pushscreen`

Comment: I just used `TouchEvent.UNCLICK`, it works well for first time which was push to `Main.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
                                new Menu_PopupMenu(position));` but when i click other button, it should work itself function but it still go `Main.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
                                new Menu_PopupMenu(position));`

Comment: Even I click the button, but it will perform the function that the current focusing object's function.

Comment: @AlanLai, so it works **one** time, and then does not work the second time?  Also, are you testing this on a touchscreen device, or no?

Comment: yup, bold 9900. Now more worst, touch also no response.

Comment: @AlanLai, I'm a little confused.  Does it work once, or not at all?  Is there a difference for the navigation click, vs. the touch event?  I'm shutting down for tonight, but I can look at this again tomorrow.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647008/unable-to-perform-another-buttons-function-if-current-button-is-focusing) I started new question but slightly difference code

Answer (score 0):

What is the parent of your Custom_ButtonField ?

If it is a buttonField, you have to set the attribute CONSUME_CLICK in the constructor